# Query to get only one row from multiple rows having same values

Tags: mysql, sql, isqlquery

I have a notification table as follows

```
|id|user_receiver|user_sender|post_id|action|date|is_read
```

here `user_sender` is the person who generated notification, `user_receiver` is one who got the notification, `post_id` is id of post, `action` can be like, comment etc, `is_read` is 1 if its read by receiver else 0

I want to get all notifications for loggedin user

query that I am using is

```
SELECT id, user_receiver, user_sender, post_id, action, 
 max(date) as date, is_read 
FROM notification 
WHERE user_receiver=$ses_user 
group by user_sender, action,post_id,is_read 
order by date desc
```

but it doesn't give me latest rows even though I am using `max(date)` and I also want to get number of notifications that are unread.

I want only one row if there are multiple rows having same post_id, user_sender and action together and that should be the latest one. For example a user likes a post, a row is added to the table, then user dislikes and likes again, then a new row is added again, I want only the new row only.

Comment: you are selecting date as max(date), you need to use it in where clause.

Comment: how do I use it in where clause, are you talking about the way @Gordon Linoff has written in his answer, if no then can you please write it in answer.

Comment: yes that's the way, I don't want to give the answer directly and want you to try on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the latest row in MySQL, you need to use a `join` or correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id, user_receiver, user_sender, post_id, action, date, is_read
FROM notification n
WHERE user_receiver=$ses_user and
      date = (select max(date)
              from notification n2
              where n2.user_sender = n.user_sender and
                    n2.action = n.action and
                    n2.post_id = n.post_id and
                    n2.is_read = n.is_read
             )
order by date desc;
```

In other databases, you would simply use the `row_number()` function (or `distinct on` in Postgres).

EDIT:

For the biggest id:

```
SELECT id, user_receiver, user_sender, post_id, action, date, is_read
FROM notification n
WHERE user_receiver=$ses_user and
      id   = (select max(id)
              from notification n2
              where n2.user_sender = n.user_sender and
                    n2.action = n.action and
                    n2.post_id = n.post_id
             )
order by date desc;
```

If you want the number of rows where `isread = 1`, then you can do something like:

```
SELECT sum(is_read = 1)
FROM notification n
WHERE user_receiver=$ses_user and
      id   = (select max(id)
              from notification n2
              where n2.user_sender = n.user_sender and
                    n2.action = n.action and
                    n2.post_id = n.post_id
             );
```

Comment: thanks...please read that last para I have edited... till then I will check this query

Comment: How do I check the number of unread notifications from this resulset?

Comment: @vikasdevde . . . Do the duplicate rows have the same date?  Can the query check for the biggest id instead of the latest date?

Comment: no the date is not same, but when I removed `n2.is_read = n.is_read` from subquery its giving proper behavior

Comment: can you edit with the check for biggest id instead of latest date

Comment: first query is good...thanks :) how do get number of rows from this resultset whose `is_read` value is set to 0 thats the one which is unread..I know I can do this by querying the same query with one more condition in where cluase that is `is_read=0` but then I will have to query again,

Answer (score 1):

Hope this post will help, there is a sample query with illustration:

```
SELECT 
    BookId, 
    BookName, 
    BookCategory, 
    BookReferenceNumber, 
    COUNT( BookReferenceNumber ) AS HowManyRecs, 
    BookDetails, 
    BookStatus
FROM 
    tbl_BOOKS
WHERE (
    BookReferenceNumber LIKE '42324%'
    OR BookName LIKE '%42324%'
)    
AND (
    BookStatus = 'Available'
)
GROUP BY 
    BookReferenceNumber
HAVING (
    HowManyRecs > 0
)
```

(Taken from [techqube.blogspot.in](http://techqube.blogspot.in/2013/12/ysql-query-to-retrive-only-one-record-for-repeating-column-or-rows-of-data-in-a-table.html))